# Curl appearing in multivariate Taylor series

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, cross-product, fluid-dynamics

This is taken from Chorin's book on Turbulence, in which he considers a function $u: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $x,h \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0 }$. Then we may expand $u(x + h, t)$ in powers of $h$ (up until $O(h^2)$) as follows:
$$u(x + h) = u(x) + \frac{1}{2}\xi \times h + D\cdot h$$
where $\xi =$ curl $u$ and $D = \frac{1}{2}(\nabla u + (\nabla u)^T)$ is the deformation matrix.

I have not seen the cross product appear in a Taylor series expansion before, where does this come from and/or is there any geometric reasoning behind it? The book mentions that $\frac{1}{2}\xi$ can be seen as a rotation vector, but this is not immediately obvious.
Similarly, why is $D$ called the deformation matrix here? How is $u$ being "deformed" exactly?

Comment: Decompose the square matrix $Du(x)$ as a sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix. The product of the skew-symmetric with the vector $h$ is the curl term.